# "..include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:error: redefinition of 'UI' as different kind of symbol" on UE4

Tags: openssl, unreal-engine4

I'm making sample for using openssl library for my game. I did add staticlibrary for Unrealengine.

(specifically,

> myproject > build settings > search paths > always search user paths : yes
>
> myproject > build settings > search paths > library search paths : /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib added
>
> myproject > build settings > search paths > user header search paths : /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/include added

Add libcrypto.a, libssl.a to Frameworks

I added codes like below at

```
MyProject.Build.cs. PublicIncludePaths.Add("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/include"); 
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib/libcrypto.a"); 
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib/libssl.a");
```

but myproject failed to build. error message was:

> "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:172:22: error: redefinition of 'UI' as different kind of symbol".

Maybe, "UI" conflicted...

When I emitted 1~3 step, it failed because of same error.

Is there anyone else know to solve this problem??

OS version : OS X El capitan(version 10.11.2)

UE version : 4.9 Xcode : Version 7.2 (7C68)

openssl library version : 1.0.2e_1

I didn't use default openssl on mac (/usr/local/bin)

Comment: Show the redefinition line.

Comment: typedef struct ui_st UI; <----- here!!

Comment: /Development/MenuTest/ThirdParty/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:170:22: error: redefinition of 'UI' as different kind of symbol
CompilerResultsLog: 정보 typedef struct ui_st UI;
CompilerResultsLog: 정보                      ^
/Users/Shared/UnrealEngine/4.9/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectBase.h:705:11: note: previous definition is here
CompilerResultsLog: 정보 namespace UI
CompilerResultsLog: 정보           ^
CompilerResultsLog: 정보 1 error generated.
CompilerResultsLog: 정보 -------- End Detailed Actions Stats ------------------

Comment: I solved the problem.
I copied openssl library and header files into subdirectory of my project and then modifed ossl_typ.h.